# Jquery прибавление чисел

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему число прибавляется только 1 раз? а не каждый раз когда нажимается кнопка

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var team2 = 0;
    
    $('#team1').click(function () {
        var team1 = team2+100;
        $('#team1_value').text(team1)
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="team1_value"></span>
<button id="team1"> 123213</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В кэлбэке click вы каждый раз создаёте переменную team1. Нужно эту переменную объявить вне кэлбэка, на уровне team2

Comment: var team2 = 0;

    var team1 = team2+100;
    $('#team1').click(function () {
        $('#team1_value').text(team1)
    }) 
Так?